# Get existance and number of rows in postgresql table with ODBC/Net

Tags: vb.net, odbc, postgresql-9.1

I am using PostgreSQL database with VB.net through ODBC what goes OK.
Sample code:

```
    Dim reader As OdbcDataReader
    Dim btCommand As OdbcCommand
    Dim mCmd As OdbcCommand
    Dim mCon as OdbcConnection

    mCon.ConnectionString = "Dsn=PostgreSQL30;database=mydb;server=127.0.0.1;port=myport;uid=myuid;pwd=mypass"
    mCon.Open()
    btCommand = New OdbcCommand("BEGIN TRANSACTION", mCon)
    mCmd = New OdbcCommand("SELECT dtbl_id, name, meas, price, qty, flag, kind FROM mytable WHERE dtbl_id >=" & brr.ToString & " ORDER BY dtbl_id LIMIT " & page.ToString, mCon)
    reader = mCmd.ExecuteReader()
    While (reader.Read())
        Dim n As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        With DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n)
            .Cells(0).Value = reader.GetValue(0).ToString()
            .Cells(1).Value = reader.GetValue(1).ToString()
            .Cells(2).Value = reader.GetValue(2).ToString()

    ... etc...
```

But I don't know how to make check if table exists and how many rows contains to VB variable with this system (odbc) so any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Solved problem by myself.

texists will finished with -1 if table don't exists, with 0 if table exists and have no rows inserted or with any integer which represents a number of existed rows in table.

Code:

```
    Dim texists As Integer = -1        
    btCommand = New OdbcCommand("SELECT 1 FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename='mytable'", mCon)
    reader = btCommand.ExecuteReader()
    While (reader.Read())
        If reader.GetValue(0) = 1 Then texists = 0
    End While

    If texists >= 0 Then
        btCommand = New OdbcCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from mytable", mCon)
        Try
            reader = btCommand.ExecuteReader()
            While (reader.Read())
                texists = Val(reader.GetValue(0).ToString())
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        End Try
    End If
```

After this, according to texists value, we can create a table, terminate program or continue with work.